# How to create these graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, polish

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to go about creating these charts?. Thank you in advance for your help

I have only this:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{polski}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{indentfirst}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{bbold}    
\usepackage{enumerate}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}    

\begin{document}    
\begin{large}    

\noindent    
\textbf {Twierdzenie 1.5 (Prawo arcusa sinusa).} \textit{Prawdopodobieństwo, że w n krokach frakcja czasu x $(0\leq x \leq1)$, w której ustalony gracz ma przewagę (stan błądzenia przypadkowego jest dodatni), dąży przy $n \longrightarrow \infty$ do}    

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int \limits_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}= \frac{2}{\pi}arcsin(\sqrt{x})$$    

Innymi słowy w bardzo długiej grze frakcja czasu \textit{x} spędzona "na plusie" ma rozkład arcusa sinusa. Oto jego podstawowe własności:\    

$\bullet$ gęstość: $f(t)= \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{t(1-t)}},$
\hspace{0.45cm} $\bullet$ dystrybuanta: $F(t)= \frac{2}{\pi}arcsin(\sqrt{t}),$    

$\bullet$ wartość oczekiwana: $\frac{1}{2},$ 
\hspace{0.5cm} $\bullet$ wariancja: $\frac{1}{8}.$\    

Wykres gęstości i dystrybuanty przedstawia Rysunek 1.5. Funkcja gęstości w kształcie litery U pokazuje, że nierówny podział czasu przewagi jest zdecydowanie bardziej prawdopodobny niż względnie równomierny.\\    


\begin{center}    
Rysunek 1.5: Rozkład arcusa sinusa.    
\end{center}    
\end{large}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please choose a meaningful title for your question. The package `pgfplots` would be an option. On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?").

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

This is essentially Mico's response. I completely agree with his upgrade of the original code. For completeness I added the intended graphs (via `pgfplots`) and use the `tasks` library as Henri Menke suggested in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page margins appropriately
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

% this is for the graphs
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
% and this for the item list
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{theorem}{4}
\setcounter{figure}{4}

\begin{theorem}[Prawo arcusa sinusa]
Prawdopodobieństwo, że w n krokach frakcja czasu $x$,
$0\leqslant x \leqslant 1$, w której ustalony gracz
ma przewagę (stan błądzenia przypadkowego jest
dodatni), dąży przy $n\to\infty$ do
\[
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}
= \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(\sqrt{x}\,).
\]
\end{theorem}

Innymi słowy w bardzo długiej grze frakcja czasu $x$
spędzona ``na plusie'' ma rozkład arcusa sinusa.
Oto jego podstawowe własności:

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
\task gęstość: $f(t)= 1/(\pi \sqrt{t(1-t)}\,)$, $0<t<1$,
\task dystrybuanta: $F(t)= (2/\pi)\arcsin(\sqrt{t}\,)$,
\task wartość oczekiwana: $1/2$,
\task wariancja: $1/8$.
\end{tasks}

Wykres gęstości i dystrybuanty przedstawia Rysunek
\ref{fig:arcusa_sinusa}. Funkcja gęstości w kształcie
litery U pokazuje, że nierówny podział czasu przewagi
jest zdecydowanie bardziej prawdopodobny niż
względnie równomierny.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,horizontal sep=1cm},
                  width=6cm,height=6cm,grid=major,samples=201,xtick={0,0.25,...,1}]
\nextgroupplot[ymax=4.5,title={Gęstość}]
\addplot [red,thick,domain=0.006:0.994]{1/(pi*sqrt(\x*(1-\x)))};
\nextgroupplot[ymin=-0.05,ymax=1.05,title={Dystrybuanta},ytick={0,0.25,...,1}]
\addplot [red,thick,domain=0:1]{2/pi*rad(asin(sqrt(\x)))};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Rozkład arcusa sinusa.}
\label{fig:arcusa_sinusa}
\dots 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that your question is about how to (re)create the graphs shown in your screenshot. However, I think your LaTeX code needs a drastic quality upgrade as well. Right now, your code performs a lot of visual formatting, with virtually no distinction between the contents and the way the contents are formatted. Please take a look at the code below for some pointers of how you might begin to adjust your writing in order to better take advantage of LaTeX's powerful formatting capabilities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.25cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page margins appropriately
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Twierdzenie}[section]
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{theorem}{4}
\setcounter{figure}{4}

\begin{theorem}[Prawo arcusa sinusa]
Prawdopodobieństwo, że w n krokach frakcja czasu $x$,
$0\leqslant x \leqslant 1$, w której ustalony gracz
ma przewagę (stan błądzenia przypadkowego jest
dodatni), dąży przy $n\to\infty$ do
\[
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}
= \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(\sqrt{x}\,)
\]
\end{theorem}

Innymi słowy w bardzo długiej grze frakcja czasu $x$
spędzona ``na plusie'' ma rozkład arcusa sinusa.
Oto jego podstawowe własności:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbullet\ gęstość: $f(t)= 1/(\pi \sqrt{t(1-t)}\,)$, $0<t<1$, &
\textbullet\ dystrybuanta: $F(t)= (2/\pi)\arcsin(\sqrt{t}\,)$, \\
\textbullet\ wartość oczekiwana: $1/2$, &
\textbullet\ wariancja: $1/8$.
\end{tabular}

Wykres gęstości i dystrybuanty przedstawia Rysunek
\ref{fig:arcusa_sinusa}. Funkcja gęstości w kształcie
litery U pokazuje, że nierówny podział czasu przewagi
jest zdecydowanie bardziej prawdopodobny niż
względnie równomierny.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption{Rozkład arcusa sinusa.}
\label{fig:arcusa_sinusa}
\dots 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For multicolumn itemizations I recommend the [tasks](https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package by @cgnieder.